# SpreadsheetApp.getUi() operation not supported?

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to add a confirmation dialog when a user clicks a menu item, I am following this Google page almost to the letter: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#alert_dialogs

However, I am getting a "This operation is not supported" error message. In the Execution Transcript, I see this:

```
[14-02-10 12:21:54:551 EST] Starting execution
[14-02-10 12:21:55:550 EST] Execution failed: This operation is not supported (line 28, file "Code") [0.226 seconds total runtime]
```

Line 28 in "Code" is the second line of the function below:

```
function sendMergedMail() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.alert(
     'Please confirm',
     'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (result != ui.Button.YES) {
    return
  }

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  doc.toast("Current sheet: "+doc.getName());
};
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is for the [new version of spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs), did you upgrade to new version ?

(just tested and works without issue)

Comment: Thank you! You are right, of course. I tried to figure out if I am using the new version of Spreadsheet. I have been to the page you linked. I assumed that I was when I didn't find the "Try the new Google Sheets." option in my settings -- I was using a Google Apps account.

Comment: Having the same issue. I can't see that option too. (I am also using Google Apps account). Personal account is showing.

Comment: The story in a nutshell to those who don't understand a thing from the above comments. In 2013 Google allowed us to write apps using its new API. Out of sudden in March 2014 they... turned off the new API. In order to keep using it, you have to "upgrade" your spreadsheet manually. [This is how it can be done](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3544847?rd=1).